# Jenkins pipeline multi condition

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which evaluates a variable to true or false, based on this I need to execute my next stage. I'm getting either pipeline failure or can't use when condition properly

Here is my snippet:

```
stage ('test status'){
`steps {'
      script {
      env['status'] = sh(script: "docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} testnode", returnStatus: true)
      }
      echo "${env.status}"
      }
      }
```

that stage gives me either 0 or 1 based on container is running or not, so if container not running I want execute a stage where I can start container 
else if already started, then kill previous container and start the new process
how can I achieve this please

tried this but fails

```
stage('test true'){
when{
environment name:'status', value: '0'
}
steps {
echo ' ------ true ----- '
}
}
stage('test false'){
when{
environment name:'status', value: '1'
}
steps {
echo ' ------ false ----- '
}
}
```

If container status returned one in 'test status' stage, this fails as first stage is testing for 0. How can I run either o or 1 condition?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.